# Creating a KieSession (Drools 6.1) in Scala

Tags: scala, drools

What is the "proper" way of creating a new Drools KieSession in Scala? The resources I've found are mostly Java-based, which I've adapted to Scala and got something of the sort (which works):

```
def getKieSession(fileName: String): KieSession = {
    val kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get()

    val kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem()
    val fis = new FileInputStream(fileName)

    kfs.write("src/main/resources/rulesfile.drl", kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource(fis))

    val kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll()

    val results = kieBuilder.getResults()
    if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
      throw new RuntimeException(results.getMessages().toString())
    }

    val kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId())
    val kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase() //Necessary?

    kieContainer.newKieSession()
  }
```

I'm trying to streamline the code and split up the functionality between calling the Kie Service and creating a new KieSession. I believe the entire method is needed to create a new session however I'm not sure the middle bit is necessary (kfs.write).

Any guidance on this? (Also, yes, still tinkering with Scala + Drools)

Comment: Given that (as you have been told multiple times!) Scala is not supported, there isn't a 'proper' way to do this in Scala. However, the usual 'recommended' mechanism is to put the DRL files in a package under `resources` and reference them from kmodule.xml. That way, you don't need to touch the `KieFileSystem`. You just grab a container from the factory and create a session from that.

Comment: Use the principle of Separation of Concerns. Create small functions which do one thing and one thing only. So create one function that sets up your knowledge base(s) and one function that can return knowledge session (s). Don't put everything in one monolithic function. @Steve, whilst I don't agree with people using Scala with Drools, in this case the OP will be fine. It is only when the Drools compiler starts getting its hands on Scala classes do things start to go bad.

Comment: I wasn't saying it should be avoided ... just that there is currently no 'proper' / 'recommended' way of doing it. :)